# Android : Retrieving and Uploading photos to php

Tags: php, android, mysql, bitmap

I am trying to retrieve and upload photos from my application. PHP is used as webservice which connects to mysql where I store the urls of images on my Computer.
I am able to retrieve images using the following code

```
conn1= (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://192.168.1.3/webservice/imageselector.php").openConnection();
conn1.setDoOutput(true);
conn1.setRequestMethod("POST");
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn1.getOutputStream());
String p="url="+url;
wr.writeBytes(p);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
InputStream stream= conn1.getInputStream();
daaaa=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream); //daaaa is a Bitmap object
```

and in php

```
$f=file_get_contents(addslashes($_POST['url']));
echo $f;
```

Now I have no idea on how to convert this Bitmap(daaaa) into some sort of string so that I can send it as a parameter for the http post request. I read other questions and tried using base64 format and also simply converting into a byte array but none worked - When I try to open the image in my server - Errors like not supported , corrupted are thrown. So how do I encode the Bitmap to send it to my php server , also what should be the php code ?

Comment: shameless plug: http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2012/06/18/membuat-file-upload-di-android-dan-php/

Comment: anyone? have been stuck on this for a week